# とやら in direct addressing

Tags: grammar, particles

I encountered this sentence.

```
「○○とやら、渡してはならんぞ。」
```

The meaning is quite obvious: “○○, you mustn’t give it to them!”

The mystery to me is the とやら there.  The meaning of “somebody called ○○” doesn’t fit here for me. The speaker already knows the listener’s name and both of them are standing in a single place. The direct addressing itself should exclude the uncertainty that やら introduces, doesn’t it?

How does the やら change the meaning there?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more of the context and the exact relation between the parties, I'd say that `とやら` adds an element of disparagement/slight: "Mr ○○ or whatever was your name, you must not hand it over".

relevant discussion: https://hinative.com/ja/questions/97950

Possibly they're playing it up for some observer...

Comment: This can make sense. The speaker and the receiver know each other only for a short time and the listener told their name only once and to somebody else. Thus your proposed meaning fits well in there.